# How to set new game defaults?

Tags: civilization-6

When ever I start a new game, it starts on defaults such as random leader, map being continents and map size small.

Is there a way to set these defaults? The game is not remembering my last setting.

Comment: I'm hoping to find something similar, but for the "Cloud Saves" option being checked. Having to re-check that every time I save/load something is very irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found great success with a mod call Restart Button.

http://civ6mods.com/2016/11/restart-button-mod-remgrandt/

You create you game and once within the game, goto the menu (where you once escaped to menu). There is a Restart button. Works with all options you set the game on. Hence if you selected random leader, usually the restarted game is with a different leader.

The other cool thing is even when you get a number of turns in you can still restart the game. (Something that Civ 5 only allowed before ending the first turn i recall).

The only downsides I have found is that the button does not work if you load a game save and does not work for the scenarios. This is less than a minor issue.

It is a huge time saver and better than exiting out to the game menu and a lot less clicks starting a new game even if Firaxis added in the saving of last game created as a default.